# session object missing while retrieving

Tags: jsf, session, jsf-2

Is it okay to retrieve session `frienddet` inside `getStatusList(`) or  should I retrieve it in a constructor and assign it to a variable. When I was running eclipse in debug mode, I found out that the `getStatusList()` function is called multiple times when the following lines of code was encountered:

```
<a4j:repeat var="p" value="#{friendBean2.statusList}"
                        iterationStatusVar="loop">
```

During the fifth time it is giving me error :

```
Error reading 'statusList' on type com.bean.FriendBean2
```

When I went to the root of the problem it turns out `frienddet` is missing in the session. This is what is driving me crazy

1) FriendBean2

```
public List<Status> getStatusList() {
        EntityManager em;
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("FreeBird");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("frienddet");
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Status s WHERE s.email='"
                + user.getEmail() + "' ORDER BY s.timeMillis desc",
                Status.class);

           // other codes

}
```

Comment: Regardless of this all, doing business logic in a getter is in any case bad.

Comment: @BalusC I know, but how should I handle this, should I call a different function in the getter to do the business logic?

Comment: Being what you want a session related value you should perform your business logic in a `postConstruct` method. I suppose FriendBean2 is somewhere defined as a `@SessionScoped` bean. Keep in mind JSF doesn't create this beans till they're called. And, yes, you should definitelly keep that value in a variable and use the getter method only to get it in your view.